# For each results in v-for loop how can I nest another v-for loop using a parameter from the results of the first loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

Using a `v-for` loop in Vue js. I am looping through the `readingTasks` data object which correctly produces two results from the data below.

```js
readingTasks:Array[2]
    0:Object
        enabled:true
        newunit:-1
        task:"The part 3 guide"
        unit:-1
        unit_task_id:27
        url:"#"
    1:Object
        enabled:true
        newunit:-1
        task:"The part 3 training units"
        unit:-1
        unit_task_id:28
        url:"#"
```

The bit I am unsure about is how for each result, how do I run another `Axios` database call that shows if the reading Task is complete or not. For example for the first record, the complete status should be true (unit_task_id:27) and the second record should be false.

```js
userTasks:Array[1]
    0:Object
        complete:true
        enabled:true
        newunit:-1
        task:"The part 3 guide"
        unit:-1
        unit_task_id:27
        unit_task_user_id:21
```

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="task in readingTasks">
    {{task.task}} 

    //trying to call a function that does an Axios call passing in parameters from readingTasks 
    {{getUserTaskByUnit(task.unit, task.unit_task_id)}}
    <template v-for="usertask in userTasks">
      {{usertask.complete}}
    </template>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
//javascript if its useful

data: {
    readingTasks: [],
    userTasks: []
},

mounted() {
    this.lastUnit();
},

methods: {

    //functons
    lastUnit: function() {

        this.tasks();

    },

    tasks: function() {
        var self = this;
        var unit = this.unit;


        axios.get("/WebService/units.asmx/GetTasks?unit=" + unit).then(function(response) {
            self.readingTasks = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);

        })
        .then(function() {


        });


    },

    getUserTaskByUnit: function(unit, unitTaskId) {

        var self = this;

        axios.get("/WebService/units.asmx/GetUserTasks?unit=" + unit + "&unitTaskId=" + unitTaskId).then(function(response) {
            self.userTasks = response.data;


        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);

        })
        .then(function() {});
    }
```

This code seems close to doing the correct thing, however `{{usertask.complete}}` flickers between true and false for both sets of results. Like it is stuck in a loop.

I would expect the first result to show True here and the second result to show False.

The part 3 guide -  true
The part 3 training units - false

Comment: where are your `userTasks` coming from?

Comment: They are coming from a sql server database via a axios call:

Comment: axios.get("/WebServiceCall/units.asmx/GetUserTasks?unit=" + unit + "&unitTaskId=" + unitTaskId).then(function(response) {
          self.userTasks = response.data;

Comment: They are in a separate database table to the reading tasks

Comment: In trying to call userTasks within the v-for loop from this code: {{getUserTaskByUnit(task.unit, task.unit_task_id)}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

The template has a dependency on `userTasks`, so every time `userTasks` changes it will cause the component to re-render, running the template again.

Every time the template runs it calls `getUserTaskByUnit` for both tasks. That will, asynchronously, update `userTasks`. When `userTasks` is updated it will trigger a re-render, which will call `getUserTaskByUnit` again, going round and round in an infinite loop.

Worse than just being an infinite loop, each time it renders it will trigger two requests, each of which will trigger another re-rendering. The number of requests will balloon exponentially.

When those requests do return you're then storing them in `userTasks`. But both responses are being stored in exactly the same place, so you'll only ever see the results of one request in the UI.

The first thing you'll need is a better data structure for storing the responses in `getUserTaskByUnit`. The simplest place to store them would be on the tasks in `readingTask`. That might look something like this:

```js
// Note the whole task is now being passed to getUserTaskByUnit
getUserTaskByUnit: function(task) {
    var self = this;

    axios.get("/WebService/units.asmx/GetUserTasks?unit=" + task.unit + "&unitTaskId=" + task.unit_task_id).then(function(response) {
        task.userTasks = response.data;
    })
    ...
}
```

The call to `getUserTaskByUnit` needs moving out of the template. Moving it into the `tasks` method seems as good a place as any. There are also a few changes required to get it to work with the new version of `getUserTaskByUnit`:

```js
tasks: function() {
    var self = this;
    var unit = this.unit;

    axios.get("/WebService/units.asmx/GetTasks?unit=" + unit).then(function(response) {
        var readingTasks = response.data;

        // Pre-populate userTasks so it will be reactive
        readingTasks.forEach(function(task) {
            task.userTasks = [];
        });

        // This must come after userTasks is pre-populated
        self.readingTasks = readingTasks;

        readingTasks.forEach(function(task) {
            // Passing task to getUserTaskByUnit, not unit and unit_task_id
            self.getUserTaskByUnit(task);
        });
    })
    ...
```

Then within the template we'd need to loop over `task.userTasks`:

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="task in readingTasks">
    {{task.task}} 
    <template v-for="usertask in task.userTasks">
      {{usertask.complete}}
    </template>
  </li>
</ul>
```

There are alternative data structures we could use depending on what other requirements you have. For example, you could retain a separate `userTasks` object to hold the `userTasks` but for that to work it would need to be a nested data structure rather than just an array. You'd need to key it by `unit` and then `unitTaskId`. The result in the template would be something like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="task in readingTasks">
    {{task.task}} 
    <template v-for="usertask in userTasks[task.unit][task.unit_task_id]">
      {{usertask.complete}}
    </template>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Much like with the earlier solution you would need to pre-populate the `userTasks`  with empty values when `readingTasks` first loads to ensure the values are reactive and also to avoid the template blowing up at the `undefined` entries. Alternatively you could use `$set` and suitable `v-if` checks respectively.

This is all quite fiddly. It may be that you can simplify it a little based on your knowledge of the system. For example, it may be possible to form compound string keys for `userTasks` rather than using two levels of nesting. Or it might be that `unit` is a prop that can be considered constant and doesn't need including in that data structure.

Comment: Many thanks, skirtle this is a very detailed answer, I now have it working as well as a better understanding of how Vue templates work in regard to rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Your `userTasks` is a view property and gets overwritten upon every call to `getUserTaskByUnit` (i.e. for each item in `readingTasks`). What you instead want is a nested structure. You should call `getUserTaskByUnit` in a loop as soon as `readingTasks` got loaded, i.e. after the line `self.readingTasks = response.data;`, and store the response as a property for every `readingTask` object.

Comment: Thank You, this was very useful.